# Change default terminal back to Bash in VS Code

Tags: command-line, bash, software-uninstall, zsh, visual-studio-code

I installed zsh in my Ubuntu 18.04 but didn't like it. After installing it I was having issues, so I removed it.

The default terminal in my VS Code has not changed back to Bash for some reason.
Whenever I open the inbuilt terminal, an error message pops up:

> The terminal process command '/usr/bin/zsh' failed to launch (exit code: 1)

[image: screenshot of the error]

I am just able to capture the screenshot - terminal gets automatically closed after fractions of a second.

Comment: Are you able to open a normal terminal, try doing `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `T`, and share results here.

Comment: Did you restart the IDE and or the System?

Comment: If successful, post the output of `echo $0`

Comment: @devGeek yes I am able to open Linux terminal with keyboard commands.

Comment: @devGeek output is 'bash'

Comment: Thanks a tonne! Kudos!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try the following steps:

1. In the VSC application open `File`>`Preferences`>`Settings`. Or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>;
2. At this point you can browse the settings, or type `terminal.integrated.shell.linux` in the search bar;
3. As value of the field `Terminal > Integrated > Shell:Linux` fill `/bin/bash`. Then restart the application.

[image]

Or, probably better, search for `/bin/zsh` and replace it with `/bin/bash`.

Comment: that solved the issue...

Comment: In my vs code, it is not in editable mode. How to solve that?

Answer (score 5):

1. Open Preferences > Settings or simply use <kbd>Ctrl + ,</kbd>.
2. Search for `Terminal › Integrated › Shell: Linux`.
3. Click on Edit in `settings.json`.
4. Finally add this line `"terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "/bin/bash"` and restart your application.

Comment: Thank you :) It worked

Answer (score 5):

New and easiest way

Configure your default integrated terminal by running the Terminal: Select Default Profile command, which is also accessible via the terminal dropdown.

[image]

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_terminal-profiles

Answer (score 0):

Open the file  `~/.config/Code/User/settings.json` and add the following line to the end of the file

```json
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux": "bash"
```

Replace `bash` with whatever terminal flavor you fancy.

Ooops i didnt notice this answer was already given by

Maddu Swaroop . Credits to him though i had to find my own despite it was there.